# How can i pass checkbox data to Textarea using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

This is my javascriptcode

```
function AddContactPhoneNo()

{ 

    $("input[name='contact_id[]']:checked").each(function(){

        var opt_value = $(this).parent().parent().children('.contacts_firstname_01_contacts').text();
        var opt = "<option value='" + opt_value + "'>" + opt_value + "</option>";
        if  (opt_value != "")
        {
             alert(opt_value);
        }
    });}
```

This is my HTML Code

```
<div class="contacts_headings_01">
                                        <div class="contacts_checkbox_01"><input name="contact_id[]" id="contact_id" type="checkbox"  value="'.$contacts_row['contact_id'].'" style="margin-top:0px ; margin-left:-3px;" /></div>
                                        <div class="contacts_firstname_01_contacts">'.$firstname.'</div>
                                        <div class="contacts_firstname_01">'.$lastname.'</div>
                                        <div class="contacts_firstname_01">'.$company.'</div>
                                        <div class="contacts_group_01_contacts_page">'.$groups1.'</div>
                                        <div class="contacts_firstname_01_contactdateofbirth">'.$birth_date.'</div>
                                        <div class="contacts_gender_01">'.$gender2.'</div>
                                        <div class="ncontacts_mobile_nmbr_01">'.$phone1.'</div>
                                    </div>
```

I Got Error like This

```
$ is not defined

$("input[name='contact_id[]']:checked").each(function(){
```

Comment: This looks like jquery syntax, have you included the jquery file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might happen the jQuery is not included ,or you're including it from a CDN where jQuery does not exists.

Another case where it might happen is in Wordpress ,you should use safe jQuery.

Instead of using the **$('selector')** you should use **jQuery('selector')** .

PS : if you're using this portion of code on a seperated JS File ,than you should Include jQuery on top of all script's on you're Document.

Answer (score 1):

Please add jquery library then this error will be solved.

Jquery Library is missing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just add above code in header section.